# atribuir linhas de uma coluna a variáveis diferentes

Tags: php, query, mysqli, variáveis

Boa tarde, sou iniciante em php e queria ajuda com um código.
eu fiz uma consulta que seleciona uma coluna e limita 6 linhas em ordem decrescente, a consulta deu tudo certo, porém estou tendo dificuldade para prosseguir. Preciso agora pegar o valor de CADA LINHA(row) da coluna selecionada  e atribuí-las cada uma delas em uma variável diferente mas não sei se existe comando para tal ou se precisa de uma logica para fazer. Se alguém souber qual o código para atribuir em variáveis diferentes cada row  da coluna me responda please!

Comment: o que você fez até o momento de código, como fez a parte do consulta, pode postar na sua pergunta ???

Comment: já descobri o erro vlws :)